# Show folder tree when using 4 terminal mode

Tags: mobaxterm

How can I show the folder tree (through SFTP) of the selected terminal when I am in 4 terminal mode?

As of now, I can see the folder tree only when in single terminal mode. But having it showing the content based on the active terminal would be very helpful for me.

Comment: What do you mean by `folder tree`? There is command called `tree` and more advanced tools like `ranger`.

Comment: I mean the content of the SSH browser. Please see here: https://fearby.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/mobaXterm-add-ssh-007-1024x722.png (it is called "SCP files" in the image)

Comment: Ah sorry. I see that your question is about "MobaXterm", that is available only on windows so I can't help you.